# How to merge many JSON files in one CSV file in NIFI?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am creating myself quite a few JSON files via AttributeToJSON processor. Here, as destination, I have set flow-file content.
Now I would like to combine them into one CSV file. I used MergeContent in my flow first to combine them into one JSON and then ConvertRecord to turn it into CSV.
However, it does not create one file for me, but many, I do not know if the problem lies in the MergeContent processor or ConvertRecord.

Or should I approach it differently?

[image: MergeContent settings]

There are my MergeContent settings

Comment: `it does not create one file for me, but many` who "it"? whish processor?

Comment: MergeContent Processor

Comment: nifi could wait for all files to merge if you have correlation attribute (attribute with common value) and each flow file has `fragment.*` attributes. Check Reads Attributes 
section here  https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue and I think the reason I'm getting multiple flowfiles is the data has slightly different schemas, due to missing values or keys in your JSON. You might have to check every record has every key (values can be `null`), so all data conforms to the same schema.